# How to get last messages from chats?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
messages( id, owner, author, message, chat_id, message_date)
```

And I want to get chat list with last message info.
How can I do that?

I tried

```
SELECT MAX(message_date), id, owner, author, message, chat_id 
FROM messages WHERE owner = ? GROUP BY chat_id
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: _How_ doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` to get the most recent message along with the corresponding date.

```
select message_date, id, owner, author, message, chat_id
from (
SELECT row_number() over(partition by chat_id order by message_date desc) as rn,
message_date, id, owner, author, message, chat_id 
FROM messages WHERE owner = ? ) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want each chat_id, but only the latest entry if several messages?

```
SELECT message_date, id, owner, author, message, chat_id
FROM messages m1
WHERE owner = ?
where not exists (select 1 from messages m2
                  where m2.chat_id = m1.chat_id
                    and m2.message_date > m1.message_date)
```

Return a row only if same chat has no later entry.